# removing white sapces from url in magento

Tags: magento

I have mageanto site and i write condition in menu listing.

That is menu active class.

I wrote this condition:

```
<li class="<?php if (Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() === $this->getUrl('about-fruit-store')):?>active<?php endif;?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('about-fruit-store')?>"><?php echo $this->__('About Us') ?></a></li>
```

but the active class is not displayed at any time.

i want to dispaly the active calss in li.
How can i do this?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you going to say, 9 characters difference are all from whitespaces? Of course it will produce that results if it is accessed from different url. Trim definitely working for removing whitespace

Comment: @ ivantedja ,i want to display the active class in <li> how can i do this?

Comment: I think you should edit your post, the main of your problem is to display active class in <li> and the problem is not because of whitespace, trim definitely working for removing whitespace. Why don't you echo the url concerted by '_' to see if there are extra spaces (I don't think the extra spaces exists) instead of echo the strlen

Comment: Try to echo '_'.Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl().'_<br>'; and echo '_'.$this->getUrl('about-fruit-store').'_<br>';

Comment: @ ivantedja ,it displays the same url:`localhost/magento_upgrade/about-fruit-store/_ localhost/magento_upgrade/about-fruit-store/_'

Comment: @ ivantedja , what i do next?

Comment: Var_dump the two statements and the if statement, they should be the same length and the if should be true, obviously it is not. If it is there should be an active. Easy going: WHY is the if false. Thats the question to answer.

Comment: @Fabian Blechschmidt , can you answer it

Comment: @Fabian Blechschmidt , i wrote the code in top of links like :`var_dump(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());
var_dump($this->getUrl('about-fruit-store'));` ,Then i got this result:`string(51) "http://localhost/magento_upgrade/about-fruit-store/" string(60) "http://localhost/magento_upgrade/about-fruit-store/" `

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two urls, are there whitespaces behind or before?

Answer (score 0):

Var_dump the two statements and the if statement, they should be the same length and the if should be true, obviously it is not. If it is there should be an active. Easy going: WHY is the if false. Thats the question to answer.